# Python regex and processing for @username

Tags: python, regex

Given a block of text I want to find all instances of @username (where username can be any username) and then check if the username is valid, if it's valid I want to replace it in the text with a link.

I know how to just replace all instances of @username with a link...but I'm not sure how to insert that check first. Can anyone help with that - given I have a function called is_valid(username) which returns True or False?

here is what I have:

```
urlfinder = re.compile(r'@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)')
urlified = urlfinder.sub(r' <a href="http://mysite.com/users/\1">@\1</a> ', text)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function as the replacement - in this case, here's a version of `is_valid` that returns the URL if the username is known, otherwise it returns what it was given as a match. You can rename this function and instead of `if uname in users`, call your `is_valid` function instead...

```
def is_valid(username, users=['@jon']):
    uname = username.group()
    if uname in users:
        return '<a href="http://mysite.com/users/{0}">{0}</a>'.format(uname)
    return uname

text1 = 'blah blah @jon blah blah'
text2 = 'blah and more blah @bob whatever'

import re
print re.sub(r'@\w+', is_valid, text1)
# blah blah <a href="http://mysite.com/users/@jon">@jon</a> blah blah
print re.sub(r'@\w+', is_valid, text2)
# blah and more blah @bob whatever
```